# vim/perl insert line when matching regex from cli

Tags: perl, vim

I have a large config file where I need to search for a variable. When I find it, I need to replace the entire line containing that variable with a specific line (say 123456).
Example:
`config.file`:

```
    $var bla bla
    bla bla $var
    simple line, no match
```

`config.file` after sed:

```
    123456
    123456
    simple line, no match
```

Edit:
I need something like `vim -c '%s/$var/123456/gc' -c 'wq' config.file`, but this only replaces the variable with the line, and not the entire line.

Is it possible to ask for user confirmation for every match of `$var`? I need to run this in cli, as I want to make it part of a script.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that Stack Overflow is about gettiing answers to *specific* questions. This is a very loose description of a program requirement and you don't appear to have tried anything for yourself

Comment: In Vim this is a single command: `:g/$var/s/.*/123456/c` but you are asking for a solution inside a script with Perl so I'm confused as to why is this tagged with Vim too. And as @Borodin said, if it is really for a Perl solution with user confirmation, give more details and show what you have already tried doing

Comment: @Borodin: I am sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question.

Comment: I've initially tried to use sed, like this: `sed -i "/$var/c\123456" config.file` which did the trick. The problem was that I had a few lines that contained $var which I didn't want to replace. After some reading: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20161/make-sed-ask-for-confirmation-before-each-replacement I've come up with the vim approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:g` command to find lines containing `$var` and then `:s` the whole line:

```
vim -c 'g/$var/s/.*/123456/c' -c 'wq' config.file
```